# Generating current date in Ruby pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

```
def event_table
    text "#{@current_date} Report", size: 30, style: :bold
end
```

I'm trying to get the current date for one of my ruby reports but the current date will not show it simply displays 'Report'

Comment: You can use `Time.now`

Comment: from where you are assigning value to this `@current_date` ?

Comment: If you need current date: `Date.today`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `@current_date` is today then try:

```
def event_table
    text "#{Date.today} Report", size: 30, style: :bold
end
```

Comment: if us `Date`, I think should add `require 'date'`

Comment: if he is storing it in `@current_date` then for sure he/she has it. otherwise @sprout add `require 'date'`